# Failed to create ISE, as i want to use this enable netorking in Logic app

Tags: azure, networking, workflow, azure-logic-apps, azure-resource-manager

using the below template

-> https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/quickstarts/microsoft.logic/integration-service-environment/azuredeploy.json

Error:

```
{
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "target": "/subscriptions/****/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/Microsoft.Template-20240320165821",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "IntegrationServiceEnvironmentCreationNotAllowed",
      "message": "New integration service environments creations are not allowed for subscription '*****'. Integration service environments are getting deprecated. Please use Logic Apps Standard instead. Please see https://aka.ms/isedeprecation for more details."
    }
  ]
}
```

can anyone plase provide the other to enable networking in logic app.

- my main auto is connect the sql server by enabling the vpc in logic app,
  as i have used the firewall also, but these ip are managed by azure, so they are changable... so that's not a good idea to connect sql server from logic app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integration Service Environment (ISE) is now deprecated for new customers and will retire on August 31st, 2024 for all customers. Logic Apps Standard is the recommended replacement.

A Standard logic app can have one or multiple workflows that run in single-tenant Azure Logic Apps or an App Service Environment v3 (ASE v3).

More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/logic-apps/single-tenant-overview-compare